# Which idtcpclient functions are thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, delphi, indy

I've already seen some indy implementations in which the main-thread sends data and the worker thread reads.

My question is regarding IdTCPClient.Disconnect, is it really thread safe? If somehow it was called in the worker thread and external thread at the same time is it really safe?

Comment: `Disconnect()` is not 100% thread-safe, but it is *mostly* thread-safe. The actual socket handle is protected by a critical section, so it will only be closed once. Worse case, calling `Disconnect()` in two threads at the same time would close the socket once and trigger two sets of `OnStatus` events for `hsDisconnecting` and `hsDisconnected` statuses, and two `OnDisconnected` events, so make sure your event handlers (if any) are thread-safe.

Comment: Remy, I'm using the Indy version that comes with RAD Studio Tokyo, are you sure that have the critical section? I don't find it, and are you sure that the problem for sync is only with OnDisconnected and OnStatus? I use only the "OnSocketAllocated", no more. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there is a critical section (the `FConnectionHandle` member of the `TIdSocketHandle` class). `Disconnect()` calls `TIdIOHandler.Close()`, which is overridden by `TIdIOHandlerSocket.Close()`, which calls `TIdSocketHandle.CloseSocket()`, which locks the critical section before closing the `FHandle` member and resetting it to `INVALID_SOCKET`. But the `OnStatus` and `OnDisconnected` events are triggered outside of any critical section lock, so there can be overlap between multiple threads.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, Yes, there is... The TIdTCPClient has the _OnSocketAllocated_ and is very usefull. Isn't there in yours?

Comment: I guess you didn't notice that I had deleted my comment about `OnSocketAllocated`.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Helped me a lot.

Comment: @RemyLebeau one last question... The function "Connected" is thread-safe too? "Result := LIOHandler.Connected;" because I can try get this result from TIdIOHandler that is not ARC on desktops and can be released by worker thread internally in indy. Is that correct?

Comment: `Connected` is NOT thread-safe. It performs a read operation, so if two or more threads call it at the same time, you risk corrupting data in the `InputBuffer`. 99% of the time, `Connected` should not be used at all. Just perform your I/O normally and let Indy raise an exception if the socket has been disconnected.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I saw on Disconnect() source the line "LIOHandler := IOHandler;", If an external thread calls the disconnect and internally in Indy releases the IOHandler at the same time, is it not possible?

Comment: the local variable is used on ARC systems to ensure the IOHandler object is alive before accessing it, since it is a `[weak]` pointer. There is no such guarantee on non-ARC systems. In any case, you should not be disconnecting the socket in multiple threads to begin with. If you are, you need to fix that. Only one thread should manage the connection. Other threads should only perform I/O on the socket, not manage the socket.